# Accidental? upgrade to 20.04.3, Xfce desktop is gone, Gnome is "unusable". What to do?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, xfce, ubuntu-studio

Sorry if this's been asked before, point me there.

I'm on a Thinkpad X230, using Ubuntu Studio, was at 20.04 LTS, ran Software Updater since my internet was good for awhile. I've always selected only LTS upgrades and it's still checked in Software & Updates but today I was bumped up to 20.04.3 for some reason, with a new (Gnome 3.36.5) desktop, and new settings menu, both inadequate IMHO (think Windows 10). There's no panel. Settings affect very little. What are my options?

Comment: The upgrade from 20.04.2 to 20.04.3 is expected; and has no consequences if you're using the GA kernel (you'll remain on the 5.4 *stable* kernel), but does mean you bump from 5.8 to 5.11 if using the HWE kernel stack (5.8 isn't supported any longer) but there are no GNOME changes; so you would have had to have had GNOME installed before hand. If you log out of GNOME, you can likely switch to XFCE desktop at the login screen (ie. the major changes are likely the consequence of something you did last session, not the *minor* bump from 20.04.2 to 20.04.3 that occurred last week...

Comment: FYI:  I still think it was something you did last session and not the upgrade (*if you upgrade your system daily; it occurred more than a week ago anyway*), but I've marked this question as off-topic (ie. *problem went away & question unlikely to help future readers*). Glad you got it fixed :)